# preg_replace random number, folder not working php

Tags: php

I want to preg_replace an string that contains a random folder name `pictures`, can be `icons`, `includes`, etc. It contains a random number as well (the name of the gif file)

```
 $regex ='/../gifs\/([0-9]+)\/(.*)/i' ;
 $title = ../gifs/pictures/83.gif;
$title =  preg_replace($regex, "" , $title);

echo $title; //expected  >  pictures
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't get _Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'_???

Comment: `$title = ../gifs/pictures/83.gif;` you realize that if that is your actual code, it isn't quoted and will throw a parse error. So, is it? Am I being too simplistic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother with regex if you can avoid it. If you know the title part is always next to last:

```
$file = '../gifs/pictures/83.gif';
$title = basename(dirname($file));
```

Or if you know the title part is always third:

```
$title = explode('/', $file)[2];
```

Comment: haha. too small code to be true. works perfectly. thank you!(6 minuts left to mark  it)

Comment: Woohoo my time spent on the code golf stack exchange has not gone to waste!

Comment: thank you for the answer. your time wasnt waste was invested, mark it!